# Can you build ASP.net User controls as assemblies?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, assemblies

Is there some setting in VS2K8 or some command line utility that can compile my user controls as .net assemblies? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use Web Deployment projects. It compiles a Web site project as a DLL.

Plug-in download:
http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=0aa30ae8-c73b-4bdd-bb1b-fe697256c459&displaylang=en

How-to video:
http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-418.aspx

General info:
[http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspxW](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please? Maybe some links?

Answer (score 2):

There is no settings provided by default to support this. But there is a hack and is explained here [ASP.NET: Reusing Web User Controls and Forms](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/tips-tricks/aspnet-reusing-web-user-controls-and-forms-000915.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to pure C# classes that subclass System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl, just create a class library project and add a reference to the project in your website.